# JFrame ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
JFrame myframe = new JFrame("My Sample Frame");
  JButton mybutton = new JButton("Okay");
```

Can someone explain to me these part.

```
 mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

  //Assuming that the content here will do something.

  }
```

Comment: visit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335161/how-does-this-method-work)

Answer (score 5):

What exactly do you not understand about the code?

The code adds an action listener to the button. The `actionPerformed` method of the action listener will be called when the button is clicked.

Note that an [anonymous inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is used here.

Comment: Hi and Thank you Jesper.
Im not used to anonymous inner class , and in fact I just knew it just by now.

.Thank you and more powers.   one last question is these practice good or bad , I mean the way I set the event listener.

Comment: This is not bad practice, in fact setting event handlers is commonly done with anonymous inner classes just like in the example you showed.

Comment: Hi Jesper, in following Line {mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()} which is part of the original question I am struggling with 'new ActionListener()' placed in brackets

It would be great if you could explain it. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepak This is Java's syntax to create an anonymous inner class. It creates a subclass of `ActionListener` on the spot, and between the `{ ... }` you can override or implement methods, such as `actionPerformed` in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

**Anonymous Inner Class is used here.**

You have technically implemented ActionListener. When you called addActionListener:

```
mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    //Assuming that the content here will do something.

 }
```

You created an instance of an anonymous class, or a class that implements ActionListener without a name.

For the same please visit  [this link .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335161/how-does-this-method-work)

Answer (score 4):

You should read this Tutorial about [writing Event Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).

Comment: +1, although you didn't really "explain" anything...you just referred OP somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a button react to events (such as a click) it must have an `ActionListener`.

In the code you posted, you are creating an anonymous class implementing `ActionListener`

```
public void mySetupFunction(){

    mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        //Do something when the button is clicked
    });
}
```

is the same as doing :

```
public void mySetupFunction(){

    mybutton.addActionListener(new MyEventHandler());
}
```

with :

```
public class MyEventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        //Do something when the button is clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is safe to assume, you are either new to Event handling or new to Java either way I have generalised the answer to accomodate both cases :)

Expert Answer:[ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

There isn't one, it's really self led and reading the APIs

Simple Answer:A sugar coated explanation of what You provided in your code.

```
mybutton
```

is a reference to the instanciated Object [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

```
xxxxxx.addActionListener()
```

is a function call to a Field inherited from class javax.swing.AbstractButton

JButton inherits [AbstractButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) fields and therefore takes us to the next explanation

```
new ActionListener(){}
```

[ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is an interface, we don't need to go this high up at all.. all we need to know is it listens for input to source from a given object

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

again this is a function call, it is the tip to our "Objects pyramid"
and not atypically - will contain the response to what you want the base of your object to do .. in this case mybutton.

What you do from here is dependent on what you want actionPerformed() to do.

The question to ask yourself if this is part of an assignment is - What does this do? How does it Do it?